# AWS API call failing with SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I am using AWS SDK and am making API calls which results in a SocketException: Connection reset. The same API call to get a list of DB instances seems to be working fine in other regions but in some regions it is failing with SocketException. The full stack trace is here

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection reset
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1114) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.257.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1064) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.257.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.257.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.257.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.257.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.257.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.257.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.257.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.rds.AmazonRDSClient.doInvoke(AmazonRDSClient.java:6241) ~[aws-java-sdk-rds-1.11.257.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.rds.AmazonRDSClient.invoke(AmazonRDSClient.java:6217) ~[aws-java-sdk-rds-1.11.257.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.rds.AmazonRDSClient.executeDescribeDBInstances(AmazonRDSClient.java:2967) ~[aws-java-sdk-rds-1.11.257.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.rds.AmazonRDSClient.describeDBInstances(AmazonRDSClient.java:2943) ~[aws-java-sdk-rds-1.11.257.jar:?]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:132) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.257.jar:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor210.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.257.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy135.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.257.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1236) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.257.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1056) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.257.jar:?]
    ... 18 more
```

This is the output of AWS CLI

```
    2018-06-22 12:33:06,048 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - CLI version: aws-cli/1.15.44 Python/2.7.5 Linux/3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64 botocore/1.10.44
2018-06-22 12:33:06,049 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Arguments entered to CLI: ['rds', 'describe-db-instances', '--region', 'eu-west-3', '--debug']
2018-06-22 12:33:06,049 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function add_scalar_parsers at 0x1ccaaa0>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,049 - MainThread - botocore.session - DEBUG - Loading variable profile from defaults.
2018-06-22 12:33:06,049 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function inject_assume_role_provider_cache at 0x185a5f0>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,049 - MainThread - botocore.session - DEBUG - Loading variable profile from defaults.
2018-06-22 12:33:06,049 - MainThread - botocore.session - DEBUG - Loading variable credentials_file from defaults.
2018-06-22 12:33:06,049 - MainThread - botocore.session - DEBUG - Loading variable config_file from defaults.
2018-06-22 12:33:06,049 - MainThread - botocore.session - DEBUG - Loading variable profile from defaults.
2018-06-22 12:33:06,049 - MainThread - botocore.session - DEBUG - Loading variable metadata_service_timeout from defaults.
2018-06-22 12:33:06,049 - MainThread - botocore.session - DEBUG - Loading variable profile from defaults.
2018-06-22 12:33:06,049 - MainThread - botocore.session - DEBUG - Loading variable metadata_service_num_attempts from defaults.
2018-06-22 12:33:06,050 - MainThread - botocore.session - DEBUG - Loading variable profile from defaults.
2018-06-22 12:33:06,050 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function attach_history_handler at 0x1b84938>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,050 - MainThread - botocore.session - DEBUG - Loading variable profile from defaults.
2018-06-22 12:33:06,050 - MainThread - botocore.session - DEBUG - Loading variable profile from defaults.
2018-06-22 12:33:06,050 - MainThread - botocore.session - DEBUG - Loading variable api_versions from defaults.
2018-06-22 12:33:06,053 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/data/rds/2014-10-31/service-2.json
2018-06-22 12:33:06,097 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/data/rds/2014-10-31/service-2.sdk-extras.json
2018-06-22 12:33:06,098 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event service-data-loaded.rds: calling handler <function register_retries_for_service at 0x13f0a28>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,098 - MainThread - botocore.handlers - DEBUG - Registering retry handlers for service: rds
2018-06-22 12:33:06,102 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.rds: calling handler <function _building_command_table at 0x1c46050>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,103 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event service-data-loaded.rds: calling handler <function register_retries_for_service at 0x13f0a28>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,103 - MainThread - botocore.handlers - DEBUG - Registering retry handlers for service: rds
2018-06-22 12:33:06,104 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.rds: calling handler <function _add_generate_db_auth_token at 0x1c42e60>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,104 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.rds: calling handler <function add_waiters at 0x1ccede8>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,108 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/data/rds/2014-10-31/waiters-2.json
2018-06-22 12:33:06,110 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - OrderedDict([(u'db-instance-identifier', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x247ac10>), (u'filters', <awscli.arguments.ListArgument object at 0x247ac50>), (u'max-records', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x247ac90>), (u'marker', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x247acd0>)])
2018-06-22 12:33:06,110 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.rds.describe-db-instances: calling handler <function add_streaming_output_arg at 0x1ccade8>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,110 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.rds.describe-db-instances: calling handler <function add_cli_input_json at 0x1860398>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,110 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.rds.describe-db-instances: calling handler <function unify_paging_params at 0x1c3d758>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,114 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/data/rds/2014-10-31/paginators-1.json
2018-06-22 12:33:06,115 - MainThread - awscli.customizations.paginate - DEBUG - Modifying paging parameters for operation: DescribeDBInstances
2018-06-22 12:33:06,115 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.rds.describe-db-instances: calling handler <function add_generate_skeleton at 0x1c2f938>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,115 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.rds.describe-db-instances: calling handler <bound method CliInputJSONArgument.override_required_args of <awscli.customizations.cliinputjson.CliInputJSONArgument object at 0x247ad10>>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,115 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.rds.describe-db-instances: calling handler <bound method GenerateCliSkeletonArgument.override_required_args of <awscli.customizations.generatecliskeleton.GenerateCliSkeletonArgument object at 0x248d110>>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,116 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event operation-args-parsed.rds.describe-db-instances: calling handler <functools.partial object at 0x24826d8>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,116 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.rds.describe-db-instances.db-instance-identifier: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x167fd70>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,117 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.rds.describe-db-instances.filters: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x167fd70>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,117 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.rds.describe-db-instances.max-records: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x167fd70>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,117 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.rds.describe-db-instances.marker: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x167fd70>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,117 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.rds.describe-db-instances.cli-input-json: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x167fd70>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,117 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.rds.describe-db-instances.starting-token: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x167fd70>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,117 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.rds.describe-db-instances.page-size: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x167fd70>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,117 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.rds.describe-db-instances.max-items: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x167fd70>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,117 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.rds.describe-db-instances.generate-cli-skeleton: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x167fd70>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,117 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.rds.describe-db-instances: calling handler <bound method CliInputJSONArgument.add_to_call_parameters of <awscli.customizations.cliinputjson.CliInputJSONArgument object at 0x247ad10>>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,117 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.rds.describe-db-instances: calling handler <bound method GenerateCliSkeletonArgument.generate_json_skeleton of <awscli.customizations.generatecliskeleton.GenerateCliSkeletonArgument object at 0x248d110>>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,118 - MainThread - botocore.session - DEBUG - Loading variable profile from defaults.
2018-06-22 12:33:06,118 - MainThread - botocore.session - DEBUG - Loading variable ca_bundle from defaults.
2018-06-22 12:33:06,118 - MainThread - botocore.session - DEBUG - Loading variable profile from defaults.
2018-06-22 12:33:06,118 - MainThread - botocore.session - DEBUG - Loading variable api_versions from defaults.
2018-06-22 12:33:06,118 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: env
2018-06-22 12:33:06,118 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role
2018-06-22 12:33:06,118 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: shared-credentials-file
2018-06-22 12:33:06,118 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - INFO - Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
2018-06-22 12:33:06,119 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: /root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/data/endpoints.json
2018-06-22 12:33:06,153 - MainThread - botocore.session - DEBUG - Loading variable profile from defaults.
2018-06-22 12:33:06,153 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x13f0230>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,157 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event creating-client-class.rds: calling handler <function add_generate_db_auth_token at 0x137b1b8>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,157 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event creating-client-class.rds: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x137b938>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,157 - MainThread - botocore.args - DEBUG - The s3 config key is not a dictionary type, ignoring its value of: None
2018-06-22 12:33:06,159 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Setting rds timeout as (60, 60)
2018-06-22 12:33:06,160 - MainThread - botocore.client - DEBUG - Registering retry handlers for service: rds
2018-06-22 12:33:06,161 - MainThread - botocore.session - DEBUG - Loading variable profile from defaults.
2018-06-22 12:33:06,161 - MainThread - botocore.session - DEBUG - Loading variable profile from defaults.
2018-06-22 12:33:06,161 - MainThread - botocore.session - DEBUG - Loading variable output from config file with value 'table'.
2018-06-22 12:33:06,161 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-parameter-build.rds.DescribeDBInstances: calling handler <function generate_idempotent_uuid at 0x13f0488>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,162 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Making request for OperationModel(name=DescribeDBInstances) (verify_ssl=True) with params: {'body': {'Action': u'DescribeDBInstances', 'Version': u'2014-10-31'}, 'url': u'https://rds.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/', 'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8', 'User-Agent': 'aws-cli/1.15.44 Python/2.7.5 Linux/3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64 botocore/1.10.44'}, 'context': {'auth_type': None, 'client_region': u'eu-west-3', 'has_streaming_input': False, 'client_config': <botocore.config.Config object at 0x1700050>}, 'query_string': '', 'url_path': '/', 'method': u'POST'}
2018-06-22 12:33:06,162 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event request-created.rds.DescribeDBInstances: calling handler <bound method RequestSigner.handler of <botocore.signers.RequestSigner object at 0x16faf90>>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,162 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choose-signer.rds.DescribeDBInstances: calling handler <function set_operation_specific_signer at 0x13f0398>
2018-06-22 12:33:06,162 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Calculating signature using v4 auth.
2018-06-22 12:33:06,163 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - CanonicalRequest:
POST
/

content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
host:rds.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20180622T163309Z

content-type;host;x-amz-date
e6281fe3d540e3e1ccd6bf0cca945a0e0af993d4dd5a6b31ca021f6fc7982b0b
2018-06-22 12:33:09,060 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - StringToSign:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20180622T163309Z
20180622/eu-west-3/rds/aws4_request
7aac3c958de1a23fdadce34453050b0c7ea8248a4c4c42234e75a9842b9e70ed
2018-06-22 12:33:09,060 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Signature:
14157a3f9e7020fbbfed088451a4be956825c398f60ea808bc374557b4e79140
2018-06-22 12:33:09,060 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: <PreparedRequest [POST]>
2018-06-22 12:33:09,061 - MainThread - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - INFO - Starting new HTTPS connection (4): rds.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com
2018-06-22 12:33:09,185 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - ConnectionError received when sending HTTP request.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 222, in _get_response
    proxies=self.proxies, timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
2018-06-22 12:33:09,186 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.rds.DescribeDBInstances: calling handler <botocore.retryhandler.RetryHandler object at 0x239e9d0>
2018-06-22 12:33:09,186 - MainThread - botocore.retryhandler - DEBUG - retry needed, retryable exception caught: ('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 269, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 317, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 223, in __call__
    attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
2018-06-22 12:33:09,186 - MainThread - botocore.retryhandler - DEBUG - Retry needed, action of: 4.9548151369
2018-06-22 12:33:09,186 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Response received to retry, sleeping for 4.9548151369 seconds
2018-06-22 12:33:14,146 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event request-created.rds.DescribeDBInstances: calling handler <bound method RequestSigner.handler of <botocore.signers.RequestSigner object at 0x16faf90>>
2018-06-22 12:33:14,146 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choose-signer.rds.DescribeDBInstances: calling handler <function set_operation_specific_signer at 0x13f0398>
2018-06-22 12:33:14,147 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Calculating signature using v4 auth.
2018-06-22 12:33:14,147 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - CanonicalRequest:
POST
/

content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
host:rds.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20180622T163314Z

content-type;host;x-amz-date
e6281fe3d540e3e1ccd6bf0cca945a0e0af993d4dd5a6b31ca021f6fc7982b0b
2018-06-22 12:33:14,147 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - StringToSign:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20180622T163314Z
20180622/eu-west-3/rds/aws4_request
3906f584b0b03701f56a963e36adb5e736bb82d187c88847d1950d3ce33e3b97
2018-06-22 12:33:14,147 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Signature:
315c7fe2e7e7bda041308d6fb15158681ee16b0ce0ebe17ef431f54344e98898
2018-06-22 12:33:14,147 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: <PreparedRequest [POST]>
2018-06-22 12:33:14,147 - MainThread - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - INFO - Starting new HTTPS connection (5): rds.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com
2018-06-22 12:33:14,272 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - ConnectionError received when sending HTTP request.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 222, in _get_response
    proxies=self.proxies, timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
2018-06-22 12:33:14,272 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.rds.DescribeDBInstances: calling handler <botocore.retryhandler.RetryHandler object at 0x239e9d0>
2018-06-22 12:33:14,272 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exception caught in main()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 208, in main
    return command_table[parsed_args.command](remaining, parsed_args)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 345, in __call__
    return command_table[parsed_args.operation](remaining, parsed_globals)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 517, in __call__
    call_parameters, parsed_globals)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 638, in invoke
    self._display_response(operation_name, response, parsed_globals)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 658, in _display_response
    formatter(command_name, response)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/formatter.py", line 69, in __call__
    response_data = response.build_full_result()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/paginate.py", line 449, in build_full_result
    for response in self:
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/paginate.py", line 255, in __iter__
    response = self._make_request(current_kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/paginate.py", line 332, in _make_request
    return self._method(**current_kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 314, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 599, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 148, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 177, in _send_request
    success_response, exception):
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 273, in _needs_retry
    caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 227, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 210, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 251, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 317, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 223, in __call__
    attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
2018-06-22 12:33:14,273 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exiting with rc 255

('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))


        2018-06-22 12:33:14,273 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exiting with rc 255

        ('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Comment: Which region are you connecting to, and from where? Are you changing any of the configuration settings from default (specifically timeout related settings)? Have you checked the [status](https://status.aws.amazon.com/) page to make sure that particular AWS service is working in that region (do other services work)?

Comment: I am trying to connect to  eu-west-3(Paris). This has been failing constantly. I am behind a proxy, but the same request works for most of the regions but fails for some with this error. I installed aws cli and it fails as well. I am adding the output of the same API call.

Comment: The command I executed was "describe-db-instance"

Comment: Funny. I had a developer having the same error (Socket Connection Timeout) yesterday while trying to download the file from S3. It turned out to be some problem with the DNS of his ISP (he was working from home). He connected to out company's VPN and the error went away.